# Snowsql.exe executable takes 23 seconds to run - best way to upload hundreds of files?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I just started using snowsql.exe to PUT parquet files to a stage, and I'm trying to ramp up but running into performance difficulties.

I've noticed that snowsql.exe is SLOW to do anything - just doing a "--help" takes 23 seconds.  I'm using powershell to iterate through folders and PUT all the files I find in the stage, and delete when I get a UPLOADED message.  However, given even 100 files, this is going to take the number of files I'm going to need to do on a daily basis, this won't scale.

The invoke-expression looks roughly like:

```
c:\progra~1\snowfl~1\snowsql.exe --config c:\my_config -c my_conn -q "PUT 'file://my/file/name.parquet' @MY.STAGE/path AUTO_COMPRESS = FALSE OVERWRITE = TRUE"
```

My thoughts are:

1. migrate to python and use the py module to PUT the files, hoping it's faster than invoking snowsql.exe.
2. change the powershell script to create a series of PUT statements as a file, then use "-f" and  executing a batch.  I'm going to have to do a little more parsing to make sure each file got uploaded properly before deleting, but not a big deal.
3. ???

Any help appreciated.  Writing this out gave me ideas, but I figured I'd ask why snowsql is so slow to begin with.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowsql is a self-extracting binary that unzips each time you run it. There's some delay there, and depending on i/o speed can take several seconds to upzip.

You can run the extracted snowsql.exe directly so it doesn't have the unzip delay each time. To do this, you can run from :

```
%USERPROFILE%\.snowsql\1.2.10\snowsql
```

Where 1.2.10 is the version that you are currently running.

Note that running it this way, Snowsql will not check for updates.